# Rails touch not cascading up models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, touch

I have a series of models like:

```
- Person
-- Blog
--- Post
---- Comment
```

when i update a comment, it touches the post model but doesnt go up the tree any further even though each belongs_to has a touch: true.

will rails only touch 1 model? is there anyway way to do this?

Comment: You could make it do it through callbacks in after_save/after_update but something like that hardly scales unless you're doing it on a relatively low scale and don't plan to have a lot of activity. See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it only goes up the tree one node since touch is only triggered when the associated model is saved or updated explicitly.  At least that is my understanding.  I also don't believe the solution @Corey mentions will work since in your case Post is not explicitly being saved/updated.  Luckily, there is also an `after_touch` callback that you can specify.

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html :

> Additionally, an after_touch callback is triggered whenever an object is touched.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to be clear you would define a callback for after_touch on the Post class, not the Comment class.